# Liquid Nitrogen Sensor LED Circuit Troubleshooting

Tags: led, sensor

I am working on a project that is intended to be an alarm system for when liquid nitrogen levels get too low. I have a sensor (The LS2 liquid nitrogen sensor from Teragon) which has included schematics for potential uses. The idea is that when the sensor is in the LN the LED and buzzer are off but when it is not in the LN the LED and buzzer turn on. The sensor outputs about 5 v when submerged and about 1.3 v when not submerged.
The included schematic in the user manual has the LED on when submerged which is the opposite of what I want. I have tried using an inverting op amp to solve this issue with no luck, any suggestions?
I have linked the schematic.[image]

Comment: This is an oversimplified diagram. When I look up this Sensor, it appears to have 2 leads. Liquid Nitrogen is non-conductive, so the sensing method is not resistive. It could be a thermistor, maybe with a slight amount of self-heating.

Answer (score 1):

Use a N-channel MOSFET on the output from the sensor and have it turn on the LED. Alternatively, use a 74-series logic OR gate.

Answer (score 1):

The output is open collector; connected to ground when the sensor is submerged, high impedance/open circuit when it's uncovered. As @winny says, use a N-channel MOSFET (a logic level device designed to be driven from 5V) and pull the gate up to 5V with, say, a 4.7k resistor for trade off between quiescent current draw and switching speed.